# How to optimize Components in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In a React project, I have certain Pages/Components which has common structure with few variations. See the code below for clarity

```
const navScrollStyle = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    marginTop: "120px",
    display: "table",
    overflowY: "auto",
    maxWidth: "auto",
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "center"
  }
}));

const navBodyStyle = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    top: "0px",
    position: "absolute",
    width: "100%",
    height: "100vh",
    textAlign: "center",
    background: "white",
    zIndex: "9999",
    height: "100%",
    overflowY: "auto"
  },
  menuButton: {
    marginRight: theme.spacing(2),
    color: "purple"
  },
  title: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    textAlign: "center",
    color: "black"
  }
}));

const gridClassStyle = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    zIndex: "100",
    flexGrow: 1,
    position: "fixed",
    top: "0px",
    background: "white",
    flexWrap: "nowrap",
    boxShadow: "5px 10px 18px #888888"
  }
}));

const FAQ = () => {
  const navBody = navBodyStyle();
  const navScroll = navScrollStyle();
  const gridClass = gridClassStyle();

  const NavPart = () => (
    <Grid className={gridClass.root} container spacing={3}>
      <BackButton />
      <NameHeader name="FAQ" /> {/* <-- Here name changes */}
      <AccountIcon />
    </Grid>
  );

  return (
    <div className={navBody.root}>
      {NavPart()}
      <div className={navScroll.root}>

        <h2>This is FAQ Section</h2> {/* <-- And the body part too */}

      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default FAQ;
```

Above is the FAQ page

Take another page

```
const navScrollStyle = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    marginTop: "120px",
    display: "table",
    overflowY: "auto",
    maxWidth: "auto",
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "center"
  }
}));

const navBodyStyle = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    top: "0px",
    position: "absolute",
    width: "100%",
    height: "100vh",
    textAlign: "center",
    background: "white",
    zIndex: "9999",
    height: "100%",
    overflowY: "auto"
  },
  menuButton: {
    marginRight: theme.spacing(2),
    color: "purple"
  },
  title: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    textAlign: "center",
    color: "black"
  }
}));

const gridClassStyle = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    zIndex: "100",
    flexGrow: 1,
    position: "fixed",
    top: "0px",
    background: "white",
    flexWrap: "nowrap",
    boxShadow: "5px 10px 18px #888888"
  }
}));

const PrivacyPolicy = () => {
  const navBody = navBodyStyle();
  const navScroll = navScrollStyle();
  const gridClass = gridClassStyle();

  const NavPart = () => (
    <Grid className={gridClass.root} container spacing={3}>
      <BackButton />
      <NameHeader name="PrivacyPolicy" /> {/* <-- Even here only name is changed */}
      <AccountIcon />
    </Grid>
  );
  return (
    <div className={navBody.root}>
      {NavPart()}
      <div className={navScroll.root}>
        <h2>This is Privacy Policy Section</h2> {/* And body part */}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default PrivacyPolicy;
```

This is Privacy Policy page

In this manner, there are certain pages which has similar structure, except the changes in NameHeader and body part.

What I've tried is created new component and written all the common code in it, but, `NavPart()` was not working hence, the page was blank.

As you can see, styles and rest of structure remains same so what is the best solution to optimize it.

What my intention is to optimize the code, so no repetition of code is required

Please look at project here: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-material-forked-71op5

Comment: The sandbox contains a lot of code. Where exactly should I look to find this not working `NavPart()`?

Comment: Thanks for response... Take an example of pages like Disclaimer, FAQ etc, there I created NavPart() which has NameHeader that changes with the component

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the easiest way is to create a so call "layout component" to contain all the common parts of the pages. For example your layout component may look like below:

```
Layout = (props)=>{
  const navBody = navBodyStyle();
  const navScroll = navScrollStyle();
  const gridClass = gridClassStyle();

  const NavPart = () => (
    <Grid className={gridClass.root} container spacing={3}>
      <BackButton />
      <NameHeader name={props.name} /> 
      <AccountIcon />
    </Grid>
  );
  return (
    <div className={navBody.root}>
      {NavPart()}
      <div className={navScroll.root}>
        <h2>{props.title}</h2> 
        {props.children}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

When you write the policy page, you may use like this:

```
const PrivacyPolicy = () => {
  return (
    <Layout name="PrivacyPolicy" title="This is Privacy Policy Section">
      {/* And body part */}
    </Layout>
  );
};
```

Comment: Well that was good solution... What if I don't want want AccountIcon in Privacy Policy page... What changes need to be done?

Comment: OK sorted out even this... passed true or false as a props in AccountIcon component

Comment: you're right. anything can be passed in as props. @Pranav